# Can I apply @ControllerAdvice to a view controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to set a default model value for *all* of my controllers, which is interpreted by my HTML template's layout (this is to add a top banner to all pages, such as to warn about upcoming maintenance). I wrote an `@ControllerAdvice` class with an `@ModelAttribute` method, and this works correctly on all of my custom controllers.

However, it does nothing when I visit a mapping registered directly with the `ViewControllerRegistry`; the method is simply never called, and `ParameterizableViewController` seems to bypass the normal binding and model generation.

Is there a way to write advice that will get applied to view controllers as well as custom controllers?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to write advice that will get applied to view
>   controllers as well as custom controllers?

For your particular use case, I recommend to register a `HandlerInterceptor` and add your common model attributes to `ModelAndView` instance in `postHandle` method. Something like following:

```
public class CommonModelInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, 
                           HttpServletResponse response, 
                           Object handler, 
                           ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        modelAndView.addObject("Favorite Quote", "Welcome to the real world");
       // Go crazy with modelAndView
    }
}
```

Also, don't forget to register your interceptor:

```
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    // Usual stuff

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new CommonModelInterceptor());
    }
}
```

Comment: I've run into issues before where the `ModelAndView` presented to `postHandle` isn't the same one as is actually used; there appears to be an invisible hierarchy with the "default" model. I need this value to be overridable by individual controllers, and I'm concerned about not reliably detecting if the value's been added to the model already.

Comment: @chrylis In order to override model attributes, i guess you could add model attributes conditionally in `postHandle`. Get current model values using `modelAndView.getModel()` and if they weren't already provided, add them.

Comment: That's what I meant about "reliably detecting", though: The `ModelAndViewContainer` creates a model hierarchy, and querying the model passed in can miss "default" (i.e., controller-provided `@ModelAttribute`) attributes.

Answer (score 0):

@ControllerAdvice and other related annotations are handled by a RequestMappingHandlerAdapter registered automatically when you use @EnableWebMcv or

Other handling methods e.g resources or view controllers are handled by HttpRequestHandler and SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter which have no knowlege of @ControllerAdvice.

You can write a custom HandlerInterceptor which is application wide to handle the common logic and use the addInterceptors method of WebMvcConfigurer to register the interceptor