# spring mvc: applying @ModelAttribute on non-@Controller endpoints

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, modelattribute, controller-advice

I've read [this suggestion on using @ModelAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33876699/how-to-make-a-model-attribute-global) for injecting parameters to the model globally. Is my understading correct, that such an approach will not cover views rendered by, e.g. `<mvc:view-controller>`, or a `form-login` custom login page?

If so, is there a way to extend such a mechanism to include all views?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended-up using an [Interceptor](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor), as laid-out in [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37215117/2564826). Registered interceptor to intercept all non-resource endpoints (using [mvc:exclude-mapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-config-interceptors)).

```
public class HandlerInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
@Override
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                       HttpServletResponse response,
                       Object handler,
                       ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
    if (modelAndView == null)
        return;
    modelAndView.addObject("foo", "bar");
}
```